# see output of print statements on android using kivy - kivy launcher

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have created a program which print some instructions on stdoutput while running . I can see them when i execute the app on windows however when i run same app on android device Samsung S3 I could not see output of print statements any where .

Sometimes we can see .kivy directory on the device in the same directory as program but those log files also contains kivy specific logs but they ignore print statement outputs .

Can any one give some advice as to how to use it ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use adb [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) to get the output of your application, or use one of the apps available on-line that help display your logs and grep for 'Python'.

Detailed steps for above::

**Enable developer options on your device**(google is your friend).
Then enable **usb debugging**.

[image]
Image taken from http://androidfannetwork.com/

Then connect your device to your pc using usb cable then type `adb devices` in your console.
It should show your device (there might be a prompt asking you for permissions to connect to the computer).

One simpler way be to use visual indication on a widget instead of printing on the console.
you could create a functions for your app `bubprint`

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<InfoBubble@Bubble>
    # declare our message StringProperty
    message: 'empty message'
    # let the bubble be of 200 device pixels
    # and expand as necessary on the height
    # depending on the message + 20 dp of padding.
    size_hint: None, None
    show_arrow: False
    pos_hint: {'top': 1, 'right': 1}
    size: dp(200), lbl.texture_size[1] + dp(20)
    Label:
        id: lbl
        text: root.message
        # constraint the text to be displayed within
        # the bubble width and have it be unrestricted
        # on the height.
        text_size: root.width - dp(20), None
''')

def bubbprint(self, message):
    message = repr(message)
    if not self.info_bubble:
        self.info_bubble = Factory.InfoBubble()
    self.info_bubble.message = message

    # Check if bubble is not already on screen
    if not self.info_bubble.parent:
        Window.add_widget(self.info_bubble)

    # Remove bubble after 2 secs
    Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt:
        Window.remove_widget(self.info_bubble), 2)
```

Comment: I tried to understand how to use adb using the link <http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html> however i could not understand what do you mean by running adb shell on shell prompt of connected device . When i connet to S3 using usb cable and runn this command on adb.exe path i get following error :
D:\Paarth\Programming\Installers\Android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\adt-
bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe shell
error: device not found

I am doing something Wrong ? How to run device s shell ? I am new sorry about asking basic questions .

Comment: Enable developer options on your device. then enable usb debugging. then connect your device to your pc using usb cable then type `adb devices` it should show your device (there might be a prompt on the phone asking to allow the pc to connect).

Answer (score 0):

Kivy launcher ignores `print()`.  So,  use `logging.info()` instead.

In main.py:

```
import logging
....
    logging.info('any strings you want to output')
```

And log files are in `.../kivy/your_app/.kivy/logs/`

Answer (score 0):

That's right, logcat doesn't pick up python print statements, as it's a java utility designed to work with the java Logger. You'll need root permission on your phone to use the .kivy/logs in a convenient manner. If you have a new-ish phone and you don't want to risk the warranty with root permissions or whatever, you can get python output accessible by logcat using python warnings module:

```
import warnings
warnings.warn('print a custom message')
```

or use a java/python package like pyjnius to create a java Logger:

```
from jnius import autoclass
Logger = autoclass('java.util.logging.Logger')
mylogger = Logger.getLogger('MyLogger')
mylogger.info('print a message')
```